# How to hide api key in getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, fetch, next.js

I try to connect my api client with next.js  This is a part of my code in index.js

```
const searchHandler = async(event) => {
const (value === '')return;
Router.push({
pathname: '/zdjatka',
query: {value: 'kotek'}});};
```

as you see i have some query params to. After trigger the handler, website is routing to my zdjatka.js, code below,

```
Test.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  const { value } = await context.query
const res = await fetch(`https://stock.adobe.io/Rest/Media/1/Search/Files?locale=pl_PL&search_parameters[words]=${value}
    &search_parameters[limit]=22&search_parameters[offset]=22`, {
          headers: {
            "x-api-key": "....",
            "X-Product": "adobe-api/0.1.0",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        })
    const data = await res.json()
    // console.log(photos); 
  return {
data: data
  }
}
```

The issue is when i switching to the zdjatka route page, the api sending a request, and chrome tools show my api-key in header, but when i open directly from webbrowser localhost:3000/zdjatka without link from index page, i get re request with data, witch did not consist api-key in header. How to achive same effect when i link with router?

Comment: You should save your api key in backend side.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a `next.config.js`, and add this inside:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
   apiKey: 'your-api-key',
  },
}
```

and then in your `getInitialProps` you can reference the API key as `process.env.apiKey`

Comment: Really? how? but I just realized you can't really hide it from the client-side, you could run a simple server to query and get the data and then send the request to your api

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for advice, i create the server

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const cors = require("cors");
app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(cors());
    server.use(bodyParser.json());
    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    server.post("/api", (request, response) => {
      // console.log(request.body);
      const datas = request.body;
      response.json({
        status: "success",
        local: datas.local,
        searchTerm: datas.searchTerm
      });

      server.get('/zdjatka', async (request, response) => {

        // const ROOT_URL = `https://stock.adobe.io/Rest/Media/1/Search/Files?locale=${data.local}&search_parameters[word]=${data.searchTerm}&search_parameters[limit]=22&search_parameters[offset]=22`;
        const url =
          "https://stock.adobe.io/Rest/Media/1/Search/Files?locale=pl_PL&search_parameters[words]=kotek&search_parameters[limit]=22&search_parameters[offset]=22";
        const fetchData = await fetch(url, {

          headers: {
            "x-api-key": "....",
            "X-Product": "adobe-api/0.1.0",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
          }
        });
             console.log(response.status);
         const data = await fetchData.json();
        response.json(data);
          console.log(response);    
        console.log(json);           

      })
    });
```

and request from page

```
 const searchHandler = async (event) => {
// Router.router.push('/zdjatka');
setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
   const data = ({local: "pl_PL",
   searchTerm: searchTerm });

const options = {
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
     body: JSON.stringify(datas)
    }
     const response = await fetch('/api', options);
     const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
 const fetchData = await fetch('/zdjatka', {

     headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
     });

       console.log(response)
     const data = await fetchData.json();
       console.log(data);                      

  }
```

the first part sending request to a server working perfectly, but i can not get response from external api.
I`ll be so thankfull for any advice! how to processing this pipe request response via server.

Problem solved, i miss try / catch.